# How to get user info from token after Bearer Token in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

If client A post username and  password to asp.net web API ,then WEB API generate a token response to client A.Next,Every time client A will send token to Web api.

Is there a way to get username from token in web api?

Comment: Did you try the method I detailed below? If so, please mark as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var username = User.Identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Auth0 for authentication in my SPA. It is token based.

In my ASP.NET Web API code, I can use the following lines to get user info:

```
string userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

string name = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
```

Hope that might help!